# Trouble clicking on a load more button using vba

Tags: vba, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to click on the `Load More` button located at the bottom of the left window of ***[this webpage](http://www.ratemyprofessors.com/search.jsp?queryoption=TEACHER&queryBy=schoolDetails&schoolID=457&schoolName=James+Madison+University&dept=select)*** using vba in combination with selenium but the script always throws timeout error pointing at this `.Get Url` line. Although it seems I've defined an accurate xpath to locate the element, I can't think further as to what I should do now to achieve the same.

How can I click on that `Load More` button?

```
Sub ClickOnLoadMore()
    Const Url$ = "http://www.ratemyprofessors.com/search.jsp?queryoption=TEACHER&queryBy=schoolDetails&schoolID=457&schoolName=James+Madison+University&dept=select"
    Dim driver As New ChromeDriver, post As Object

    With driver
        .Get Url
        Set post = .FindElementByXPath("//div[contains(.,'Load More')]")
        .ExecuteScript "arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", post
        post.Click
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: In my chrome browser this worked if you want to try it: document.getElementsByClassName("progressbtnwrap").item(0).click()

Answer (score 1):

I see two "Load More" buttons. Both are matched by `"//div[contains(.,'Load More')]"`. The first one is hidden. You need to handle second one.

Try this XPath

```
"//div[@class='content' and . = 'Load More']"
```

Answer (score 1):

At least for me there were a couple of banners to dismiss as well as scrolling. There was no problem with the get line

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ClickOnLoadMore()
    Const Url$ = "http://www.ratemyprofessors.com/search.jsp?queryoption=TEACHER&queryBy=schoolDetails&schoolID=457&schoolName=James+Madison+University&dept=select"
    Dim driver As New ChromeDriver, post As Object

    With driver
        .get Url
        If .FindElementsByCss(".close-notice.close-this").Count > 0 Then
            .FindElementByCss(".close-notice.close-this").Click
        End If
        .SwitchToFrame .FindElementByCss("[id^='spout-unit-iframe']")
        With .FindElementByCss("#spout-ads #spout-header-close")
            .ScrollIntoView
            .Click
        End With

        .SwitchToDefaultContent
        .ExecuteScript "document.querySelector('.result-list [onclick*=LoadMore]').scrollIntoView(true);" & _
                       "window.scrollBy(0, -(window.innerHeight - this.clientHeight) / 2);"

        .FindElementByCss(".result-list [onclick*=LoadMore]").Click
         Stop '<== Delete me later
        'other code
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: In order to check your script I need my make my script get past this line `.Get Url` but can't. How weird!!!

Comment: I understand completely. I’m sorry I couldn’t replicate that step. Thoughts that occurred to me: is it possible this site is preventing your access? Did you have access once and no longer via selenium? Have you varied the .get timeout?

Comment: My script does open that site via selenium and get there stuck like what I said. I could not understand what you meant by varied here? Thanks @QHarr.

Comment: Varied.. you know that .get had an optional timeout argument? You can specify a longer timeout

Comment: Struggling to find the use case of `optional timeout argument`  @QHarr.

Comment: For example:  .get Url, timeout:=10000  Not sure how helpful as I am unsure on reason you are stuck on this line. This argument simply allows you to extend the timeout before error thrown.